# Slider x and y position in qml

Tags: qt, qml, slider, orientation

I want to user Slider for both vertical and horizontal orientation.

```js
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Slider {
    id: control 

    property bool sliderVertical: true

    width: 300
    height: 220
    rotation: sliderVertical ? 90 : 180
    x: sliderVertical ? -50 : 50
    y: sliderVertical ? 100 : -100

    background: Rectangle {
        x: sliderVertical ?  control.leftPadding + (control.availableWidth - width) / 2 : control.leftPadding
        y: sliderVertical ? (control.topPadding + (control.availableHeight - height)) / 2 : control.topPadding + (control.availableHeight/2 - height/2)
        implicitWidth: sliderVertical ? 10 : 300
        implicitHeight: sliderVertical ? 300: 10
        border.color: "#353637"
        color: "red"
        Rectangle {
            width: control.visualPosition * parent.width
            height: parent.height
            color: "#21be2b"
            radius: 2
        }
    }

    handle: Rectangle {
        x: control.leftPadding + control.visualPosition * (control.availableWidth - width)
        y: control.topPadding + control.availableHeight / 2 - height / 2
        implicitWidth: 26
        implicitHeight: 26
        color: control.pressed ? "#f0f0f0" : "#f6f6f6"
        border.color: "#bdbebf"
    }
}
```

I am trying above piece of code. But i am not able to understand how x and y for background rectangle and handle rectangle is set. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: I see no [horizontal :true](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-slider.html#horizontal-prop). Is `rotation` does this function? For what all these tricks with sizing?

Comment: yes rotation also serve this purpose of horizontal and vertical alignment.

Comment: Ok, so what about [Slider.orientation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-slider.html#orientation-prop) the purpose of which is to define the orientation in "right" way?